# How can I update php through homebrew

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, macos-big-sur

My previous php version is 7.3 and it was default in mac os. After installing new PHP version 7.4 with homebrew I update the php path.
When I run php --version it shows me php v7.4.23 but when I run any php code it doesn't work. I think I need to do some configuration in my settings. I follow some tutorial but nothing resolve my issue

Whenever I run any php it gives me this error

```
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/Users/Raymond Tucker/projects/test/vue-test/foridpur_ict/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.22/share/php@7.4/pear') in /Users/Raymond Tucker/projects/test/vue-test/foridpur_ict/artisan on line 18
```

This is my output of $ where php

```
➜  ~ where php
/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin/php
/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin/php
/usr/local/bin/php
/usr/bin/php
➜  ~
```

Comment: Please correct your apache setting. you have to point to the correct version of PHP which you are using.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question, and add more info about "I run any php code it doesn't work.".  What error are do you see? How do you start PHP? What exactly is the issue (besides the fact that "it is not running")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the new PHP version you have to edit the Apache file:

Open the httpd.conf file and find the LoadModule. it should have the correct version of the PHP. It will look something like this:-

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.3/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
```

What you have to do is, change this to point to the correct version of the php.

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.4/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
```

Comment: How can I open the httpd.conf file. I didn't install it thrught xammp I install it through homebrew

Comment: for me its present at /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf. Try to locate the conf file.

Comment: @ziasultan, if it worked, can you please accept my answer.

Comment: thanks for the answer but it's not working yet cause I don't have the httpd installed

Comment: @ziasultan, so how are you serving the php content? what is the webserver you are using ? its not apache ?

Comment: Whenever I try to run my laravel project with php artisan serve it gives me this error
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/Users/Raymond Tucker/projects/test/vue-test/foridpur_ict/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.22/share/php@7.4/pear') in /Users/Raymond Tucker/projects/test/vue-test/foridpur_ict/artisan on line 18

Answer (score 0):

I have Mac El Capitan. Nothing worked for me except [this article](https://edwindiaz.com/how-to-update-php-on-mac-os-x-fast-and-easy/) (super fast).

It allowed me to update php5 to php7, I don't know why, and honestly I don't feel it was real, but I don't understand how has the php5 became php7.

Back in the day, I did it with Macports, but I couldn't install Macports this time, so I had to use this new method.

Comment: Links as an addendum to an answer are welcome, but an answer consisting entirely of a link may be deleted. Would you edit this to give a summary of the technique you are recommending?

Comment: camarade, you can delete.
i don't understand the link; all it helped me is to update .
i thought updating php will help me solve the php code not running instead of showing

Answer (score -1):

Although not a direct answer to your question Mamp pro enables you to switch PHP versions easily. It made my development life much easier.